# How can I disable laravel spatie signature?

Tags: node.js, laravel, laravel-8, webhooks

I am receiving a webhook from a node js server. Anytime the laravel webhook endpoint is hit by the node it returns the error `The signature is invalid.
How can I disable the default signature from laravel spatie or write my own signature? Or even better: how do I send a signature from the node server that will be accepted by [laravel spatie](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-webhook-client)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using laravel-webhook-client there's a [section in their documentation](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-webhook-client#verifying-the-signature-of-incoming-webhooks) that tells you how the signature is verified:

> Verifying the signature of incoming webhooks
> This package assumes that an incoming webhook request has a header that can be used to verify the payload has not been tampered with. The name of the header containing the signature can be configured in the signature_header_name key of the config file. By default, the package uses the DefaultSignatureValidator to validate signatures. This is how that class will compute the signature.

> $computedSignature = hash_hmac('sha256', $request->getContent(), $configuredSigningSecret);
> If the $computedSignature does match the value, the request will be passed to the webhook profile. If $computedSignature does not match the value in the signature header, the package will respond with a 500 and discard the request.

If you want to keep the signature verification in place, create a signature and add to the request header in Node using the mechanism as above.

If you don't want to ignore the signature, send a blank header and create your own SignatureValidator class along the lines of:

```
class YourSignatureValidator implements SpatieSignatureValidator {
  public function isValid(): bool {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Then point to that validator class in the configuration as [mentioned here](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-webhook-client#creating-your-own-signature-validator):

```
'signature_validator' => \App\YourSignatureValidator::class,
```